# Measuring optical density with/without re-suspending cells

Tags: microbiology, lab-techniques, cell-culture, growth, assay-development

When measuring absorbance using a plate reader, is it necessary (or better) to resuspend the culture if the plate has been sitting still for 1-2 days?

While this could be a good physics question, I am more interested in the correct biological assay technique.

--

The two options are:

1) growing microbes in a plate inside a static incubator and then put the plate in a plate reader **without** agitating the liquid

2) growing microbes in a plate inside a static incubator and then put the plate in a plate reader **after** agitating the liquid

In option 2, the agitation could be achieved by gently pipeting the liquid up and down a few times...

Answer (score 1):

Definitely (2). Clumps of cells will cause a lot of noise in your absorbance measurements (depending on whether the light beam hits a clump or some empty space).

I don't know what your microbe is or what growth medium you're assaying on, but typically it's very important to maintain the culture well-mixed at all times, not just during measurement. If your cells clump to the bottom, you will not get the same aeration as you will if they're well-mixed, and accessibility of other nutrients could potentially be limited as well. Generally the most controlled condition is to maintain good mixing at all times, but certainly this is organism- and medium-dependent.

Comment: +1 If a liquid culture had been standing for a few days with no shaking, there must be many dead cells. Shake or no shake, the OD will be misleading.